# White space between two inputs in a form

Tags: html, css

I`m making a form with this code
HTML

```
<form id="advanced_search" action="" class="clearfix">
        <input type="text" id="check_in_date" placeholder="Check In Date">
        <input type="text" id="check_out_date" placeholder="Check Out Date">
        <input type="text" id="min_price" placeholder="Min. Price">
        <input type="text" id="max_price" placeholder="Max. Price">
        <input type="text" id="keywords" placeholder="Keywords">
    </form>
```

CSS

```
#advanced_search {display: none;}
#advanced_search input 
{
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #cbe0f4;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    border: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: 20px 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
input:focus {outline: 0}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: #95badf;
}
#advanced_search input:last-of-type {
    width: 100%
}
#max_price,
#check_out_date {
    float: right;
}
#advanced_search
#check_out_date {
    background: #cbe0f4 url(img/calendar_icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 80% 50%;

}
#advanced_search #check_in_date {
    background: #cbe0f4 url(img/calendar_icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 80% 50%;
}
```

But in Google Chrome it have a white line like this between two inputs
What should I do to fix this problem? Thanks

http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2015-11/09/a7knga1law0v.png

Comment: please set up a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net so we can reproduce the problem. I don't have an image debugger :)

Comment: fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wmhm5001/ (removed first line of css)

Comment: you can reproduce the problem in chrome resizing fiddle's frames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line is caused by the white space between the elements:

```
<input type="text" id="check_in_date" placeholder="Check In Date">  //white space is here
<input type="text" id="check_out_date" placeholder="Check Out Date">
```

You can remove it with this style:

```
#advanced_search input {
  float: left;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oba6snv6/)

Answer (score 1):

Or if you hate floats you can set a font size 0 on the container div, and display them inline block:

```css
#advanced_search {
  font-size: 0;
}
#advanced_search input {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #cbe0f4;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 20px'Lato', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}
input:focus {
  outline: 0
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #95badf;
}
#advanced_search input:last-of-type {
  width: 100%
}
#advanced_search #check_out_date {
  background: #cbe0f4 url(img/calendar_icon.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 80% 50%;
}
#advanced_search #check_in_date {
  background: #cbe0f4 url(img/calendar_icon.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 80% 50%;
}
```

```html
<form id="advanced_search" action="" class="clearfix">
  <input type="text" id="check_in_date" placeholder="Check In Date">
  <input type="text" id="check_out_date" placeholder="Check Out Date">
  <input type="text" id="min_price" placeholder="Min. Price">
  <input type="text" id="max_price" placeholder="Max. Price">
  <input type="text" id="keywords" placeholder="Keywords">
</form>
```